# Store name appears twice in meta titles while searching in Google?

Tags: google-search, magento, title

In Google,

While searching my (`Magento`) site, the `meta title` appears twice.

I am new to Magento, and don't know why it's `appearing twice`.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a SEO plugin for Magento?

Comment: @Zistoloen no we don't use the plugin.

Comment: Presumably the title ("My Store Name") is not appearing twice in the source of the page?

Comment: Reiterating the question asked elsewhere that got ignored. As @w3d asks, does this show twice when you do a view source of the pages that Google does this on?

Comment: @Fiaso labs no while viewing in source code it does not show twice only in google search it appers twice.

Comment: Google does customise the title and description shown in the SERPs based on what you search for, it isn't necessarily lifted straight from the `title` tag. So it might be possible that Google is finding this text in `Hn` tags elsewhere on the page (or in close proximity to where the search phrase is found) and is seeing it as relevant to your search? These search results do seem a bit odd(?) - are these _localised_ search results? "Google Products"? Try searching for another phrase that returns this page in the SERPs - is the title any different?